# How to convert a continuous probability density function into discrete samples?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

What are the different methods that can be used to convert a probability density function of a continuous random variable into a discrete random variable? I have studied the uniform width method but are there other methods that give better approximations?

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat broad.  It is is a continuous distribution whose support is the whole of $\mathbb R$, then its cumulative probability distribution function $F$ is continuous and strictly increasing.  In that case, if $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ is an i.i.d. sample from the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$, then $F^{-1}(U_1),\ldots,F^{-1}(U_n)$ is an i.i.d. sample from the distribution whose c.d.f. is $F$.

But there is a lot more to say about it. Enter the term "stochastic simulation" on amazon(dot)com and in a library catalog and you should see lots of stuff.